# OSX/Cocoa : get Absolute position of docktile icon in screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, position, nsdocktile

I am wondering if there is a way to find the absolute position of a docktile in the screen without using the accessibility API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Apple's [DockTile example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DockTile/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004391)?

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to my question... there is nothing in the code regarding position unless I overlooked something.